# Setting quartz schedule with startdate and timezone

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have the following method to schedule a job to fired at different timezone and start date.

If the server's timezone is Asia/Taipei, and the schedule is set to the following inputs:

```
triggerName="testTrigger",
jobName="testJob", 
group="testGroup", 
startDate = 2014-12-03 18:00:00
timezoneString = "Austrailia/Melbourne"
cronExp = 0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *
```

When should be the firing time?

```
  public void schedule(String triggerName, String jobName, String group, Date startDate,       String timezoneString, String cronExp){
    try {
        JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail(jobName, group, MessageJob.class);

        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneString);
        Date startDate = startDate;

        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.setTime(startDate);
        cal1.setTimeZone(timeZone);
        startDate = cal1.getTime();

        CronTrigger cronTrigger = new  CronTrigger(triggerName, group, jobName, jobGroup, startDate, null, cronExp, timeZone);
        scheduler.start();

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("ParseException issues " + e.getMessage());
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        System.out.println("IllegalArgumentException issues " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you explicitely set a different timezone in a Quartz cron trigger, then the trigger will fire according to the trigger configuration in the specified time zone. I.e. your cron trigger expresion will be evaluated using the Australia/Melbourne timezone.

To prove this, I created a sample cron trigger with the Australia/Melbourne time zone in [QuartzDesk](https://www.quartzdesk.com). My local timezone is CET (Central European Time). In the GUI you can clearly see that the trigger's next fire time as returned by Quartz is 2014-12-04 14:00:00 (in the local CET time zone).

[image: Australia/Melbourne trigger in QuartzDesk]

Now when you convert this time to the Australia/Melbourne timezone (I use this [online converter](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html)), I get 2014-12-04 00:00:00 which is the expected trigger time:

[image: Midnight in Australia/Melbourne timezone = 14:00:00 in CET timezone]

As for when your cron expression (0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *) fires, it fires every minute on every hour (01:00:00, 01:01:00,...) in the Australia/Melbourne timezone. Now considering that Taipei is Australia/Melbourne + 3 hours, then the fire times in your timezone will be 21:01:00, 21:02:00, ...